# Auto-Inserting <br /> tags using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS and I want to minimize the amount of tagging I am doing in an HTML document.

Is there a way to define newlines as having `<br />` so that for a given `<div>` that I've defined I can do the following:

```
.description {
        br: on;
    color: #D3E22A;
    width: wrap; 
}
```

Comment: pre tags or "white-space: pre" will work, but I think it might be good to if you could share why you want to minimize tags.

Comment: because verbose hand-tagging is boring.
i'd rather focus on design.  :)

Comment: thanks- yea; i'm also new to this site.  :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
white-space: pre;
```

or

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

See [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-prop).

Answer (score 2):

```
white-space: pre;
```

this makes it just like a `<pre>` element.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a tool to allow you to enter text in paragraph form without needing to write your own markup for it.  You probably want a WYSIWYG editor.  There are free JavaScript implementations that offer nice input formatting tools.

You definitely don't want to insert 
 tags with CSS - that is just nonsense.  CSS defines formatting for markup.  It doesn't create new markup.

If you want to apply some sort of markup transformation, use JavaScript or a server-side scripting language.  CSS is not a general-purpose programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Well , if you have a text an you nave a new-line, it means , 
that you have began a new paragraph - a `<p>` tag.
Try reading this article : 
http://brainstormsandraves.com/articles/semantics/structure/

Basicly that, what you call a "newline", is caused by a begining of a new block level element.
A paragraph is a block level element.
And for all block-level element you can set a verticla margins and paddings.

Recommended readoing:
 - http://www.htmldog.com/guides/
 - http://wsc.opera.com/